# memory issue in the method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am running application in leak's i found 20% for memory issue.

```
-(void)createLabel{

iconTitle=[[UICustomLable alloc]initWithMenuFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 80, 60) text:TAB_LANDSCAPE_WALL];
    [myView addSubview:wbgImg];
    [myView addSubview:iconTitle];
    iconTitle=nil;


    iconTitle=[[UICustomLable alloc]initWithMenuFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 80, 60) text:TAB_WALL];
    [myView addSubview:wbgImg];
    [myView addSubview:iconTitle];
    iconTitle=nil;
}
```

even i release it also

```
-(void)createLabel{

iconTitle=[[UICustomLable alloc]initWithMenuFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 80, 60) text:TAB_LANDSCAPE_WALL];
    [myView addSubview:wbgImg];
    [myView addSubview:iconTitle];
        [iconTitle release]; 
    iconTitle=nil;


    iconTitle=[[UICustomLable alloc]initWithMenuFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 80, 60) text:TAB_WALL];
    [myView addSubview:wbgImg];
    [myView addSubview:iconTitle];
    [iconTitle release]; 
        iconTitle=nil;
}
```

I am calling this method in viewdidload

```
[self createLabel];
```

@All

can any one help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should always release an object when you call `alloc` and `init`, `copy` or `new`.

You can find some memory leak when using the `analyze`. Goto product -> analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `UICustomLable` class doesn't contain a memory leak and use your second solution with the `release` keyword. Also delete the app from the device/simulator and clean the project (cmd+shift+k) and then rebuild it and try it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your UICustomLable has no memory leaks then it seems you allocate memory for "wbgImg" in your init method. Make sure you release it in dealloc.

In iOS 5.0 there is a new technology called ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), basically you won't need to worry about this in the future.